# Как на PHP остановить зациклившийся процесс?

Tags: php, исключения, циклы, время, limit

Как остановить такой скрипт нe трогая сам цикл?

```
<?php
    $start = time();
    function checkExecutionTime()
    {
        set_time_limit(0);
        while (1)
        {
            $i++;
        }
    }
checkExecutionTime();
$maxTime = time() - $start;
if($maxTime > 20){
    $timeoutMsg = 'Timeout on '.$_SERVER['REQUET_URI'];
    echo $timeoutMsg;
    file_put_contnts('timeoutLog.log' , $timeoutMsg, FILE_APPEND);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Написав бесконечный цикл `while` я сэмулировал тормоз ,но так думаю что это может возникнуть и из за выборки или другой какой нибудь операции которая долго выполняется `(SLCT * FROM ....)`.Код очень большой.То Есть много `controllers` и `actions` .Невозможно пройтись по всем и продебажить :(

Мне нужно остановить данный процесс для этого пользователя,и понять на какой странице он застрял.Aто получается что из за него процессор жрет всю память А остальные пользователи не могут открыть другие страницы потому что тоже висят.

Есть кто нибудь кто бы сталкивался с такой проблемой ?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Можно сделать форк до того как скрипт уйдет в опасную секцию. В форкнутом процессе периодически проверять время. Если родитель превысил лимит, то послать команду на убийство. При выходе из опасной зоны убивать дочерний процесс.

Comment: Классно сказано.А как ?

Comment: Зависит от системы. В posix совместимых можно использовать расширение pcntl ([pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php) - для форка, [pcntl_signal](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-signal.php) - для отсылки комманд) и [usleep](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usleep.php) для того чтоб спокойно ждать некоторое время. Для windows скорее всего тоже есть какойнить плагин.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ещё механизм [`ticks`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks)

```
declare(ticks=10000);

$timerUntil = microtime(true) + 1;
register_tick_function(function() use($timerUntil) {
    if ($timerUntil < microtime(true)) {
        throw new \LogicException('timeout');
    }
});

function foo() {
    for (;;) {}
}

try {
    foo();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Указанная в `register_tick_function` функция будет вызываться раз в указанное в declare количество операций PHP. Вполне допустимое место для кидания исключения.

Стектрейс вполне приличный сохраняется:

```
exception 'LogicException' with message 'timeout' in /home/melkij/test.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 /home/melkij/test.php(13): {closure}()
#1 /home/melkij/test.php(17): foo()
#2 {main}
```

А Closure через `unregister_tick_function` отключить довольно-таки нетривиально, не имея самого Closure под рукой.

Comment: set_time_limit(0); Поставьте в начале кода.У втора как я понял такая проблема

Comment: Честно говоря ничего не получилось у меня :( .set_time_limit(0);Когда стоит эта функция то никакой max_execution_time = 30 нe помогает.

Comment: Не понял в чём у вас проблема. С вызовом `set_time_limit(0);` аналогично функция отстреливается. Тестирую на 5.6